# How to show PASSED tests in Jenkins test results

Tags: jenkins, junit

Once Jenkins job is done it will display all and failed tests but there are no passed tests. I need this for my mail notification. It would be more convenient for me to have here a list of all passed tests:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9W1p0.png)

Answer (score 0):

Allow me to answer to myself: You just need to update a bit existing html emial notification: https://github.com/jenkinsci/email-ext-plugin/blob/master/src/main/resources/hudson/plugins/emailext/templates/html.jelly
Read this also to know where to put new file:
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=59506969
Copy this part of file

```
<!-- JUnit TEMPLATE -->

<j:set var="junitResultList" value="${it.JUnitTestResult}" />
<j:if test="${junitResultList.isEmpty()!=true}">
  <TABLE width="100%">
    <TR><TD class="bg1" colspan="2"><B>JUnit Tests</B></TD></TR>
    <j:forEach var="junitResult" items="${it.JUnitTestResult}">
      <j:forEach var="packageResult" items="${junitResult.getChildren()}">
        <TR><TD class="bg2" colspan="2"> Name: ${packageResult.getName()} Failed: ${packageResult.getFailCount()} test(s), Passed: ${packageResult.getPassCount()} test(s), Skipped: ${packageResult.getSkipCount()} test(s), Total: ${packageResult.getPassCount()+packageResult.getFailCount()+packageResult.getSkipCount()} test(s)</TD></TR>
        <j:forEach var="failed_test" items="${packageResult.getFailedTests()}">
          <TR bgcolor="white"><TD class="test_failed" colspan="2"><B><li>Failed: ${failed_test.getFullName()} </li></B></TD></TR>
        </j:forEach>
      </j:forEach> 
    </j:forEach>  
  </TABLE>  
<BR/>
</j:if>
```

paste it again and change it slightly:

```
<!-- JUnit TEMPLATE -->

<j:set var="junitResultList" value="${it.JUnitTestResult}" />
<j:if test="${junitResultList.isEmpty()!=true}">
  <TABLE width="100%">
    <TR><TD class="bg1" colspan="2"><B>JUnit Tests</B></TD></TR>
    <j:forEach var="junitResult" items="${it.JUnitTestResult}">
      <j:forEach var="packageResult" items="${junitResult.getChildren()}">
        <TR><TD class="bg2" colspan="2"> Name: ${packageResult.getName()} Failed: ${packageResult.getFailCount()} test(s), Passed: ${packageResult.getPassCount()} test(s), Skipped: ${packageResult.getSkipCount()} test(s), Total: ${packageResult.getPassCount()+packageResult.getFailCount()+packageResult.getSkipCount()} test(s)</TD></TR>
        <j:forEach var="passed_test" items="${packageResult.getPassedTests()}">
          <TR bgcolor="white"><TD class="test_passed" colspan="2"><B><li>Passed: ${passed_test.getFullName()} </li></B></TD></TR>
        </j:forEach>
      </j:forEach> 
    </j:forEach>  
  </TABLE>  
<BR/>
</j:if>
```